# assign a shortcut key AND hide macro

Tags: excel, vba, key, shortcut

I am at a dead end, i have been trying to hide all macros, I have been able to do all macros that do NOT have a short Key assigned by Private Sub, but whenever i use Private on a macro that has a shortcut key assigned it doesn't not work, in fact, it disables the shortcut key

I have tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "+Q", "Macro1"
End Sub
```

and that doesn't work, yes I placed it in This Workbook.....of course if i take Private out of the macro and run it works fine.  I have tried <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and that doesn't work either

there has to be a way, isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, if you need capital "Q" then you need to do:

```
Application.OnKey "^+Q", "Macro1"
```

Also, it isn't necessary to make the macros *private* in order to hide them from the ribbon/macros menu. Here is a workaround that I use:

Any macro/subroutine will be 'hidden' (not displayed in the list of macros from the Ribbon/menu) if it takes at least one argument.  So one workaround for you is to just add an optional, meaningless argument for each subroutine, and then you can leave them as public subs.

Example:

```
Sub Macro1(Optional dummy)
    MsgBox "Hi!"
End Sub
```

The above macro should *not* appear in the list of available macros, but it should still work with your hotkey.

Comment: +1 great and specific workaround. Have you ever tried with hidden modules?

Comment: oh no nvm I got too carried away :)